# how to change the date format of sqlserver 2008

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, date, ruby-on-rails-4, date-format

By default in sqlserver date will be stored in "yyyy-mm-dd" format, but as per my requirement in my rails app I need to change the format to "mm-dd-yyyy".
How can I do that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, if you're storing data in `datetime`, `date` or `datetime2` columns, it's stored in a binary encoding that doesn't *have* a format. You should keep the data in columns or variables that accurately maintain the date information (I presume Ruby also have some suitable "date" data type and that the data access facilities support translating SQL's date data types into the Ruby ones). Only when you're actually showing it to the user should you actually transform it into a string, and it's at *that* point that formatting concerns arise. That's nowhere near the database.

Answer (score 1):

> By default in sqlserver date will be stored in "yyyy-mm-dd"

No, `date` is stored as a 3 byte value. [date (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx)

> I need to change the format to "mm-dd-yyyy"

That means that you have to stop using the `date` datatype and instead use `char(10)` and convert from `date` to `char(10)` using the style 110.

```
declare @D date
set @D = getdate()
select convert(char(10), @D, 110)
```

I would recommend not to do this. Keep it as date and format wherever you need to display the date.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert while selecting that column from table

```
 select convert(varchar,DateColumnName,101) as DateColumnName from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

First Check default date format `dbcc useroptions`
Then change it using `SET DATEFORMAT mdy;`

and then check the changes again `dbcc useroptions`